# Invalid Date in Date Math String error while creating indexes using Django 1.9 and Solr 6.1

Tags: python, django, datetime, solr

I'm trying to implement a search in my Django project using Solr and their interaction module PySolr, which operates via Haystack. I was able to properly configure Solr, but when I run the command python `manage.py rebuild_index`, I get the error `Invalid Date in Date Math String`.

According to the [official documentation of Solr](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates), the Solr datetime format is `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ` (e.g. `2016-07-13T14:31:07.237204Z`), but the datetime format in PySolr, probably, is `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+TT:TTZ` (e.g. `2016-07-13T14:31:07.237204+03:00Z`), where `TT:TT` is timezone offset (the hours and minutes respectively).

My code in search_indexes.py:

```
from haystack import indexes
from .models import Item

class ItemIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
    updated = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='updated')

    def get_model(self):
        return Item

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to the problem was very simple. Haystack backend has `prepare_FOO(self, obj)` function, where `FOO` is one of the indexed fields. This function allows you to update the obtained value before indexing for each `FOO` element. Thus, we can perform postprocessing for each datetime in `updated` field and bring it to the default Solr format.

In my case the code is looks like this:

```
class ItemIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
    updated = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='updated')

    def get_model(self):
        return Item

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()

    def prepare_updated(self, obj):
        updated = u''

        if 'updated' in self.prepared_data:
            updated = self.prepared_data['updated'].strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

        return updated
```

`prepare_updated(self, obj)` function takes each datetime in `updated` field during the indexing and converts it to `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ` form.